# How to draw Benzo(k)fluoranthene with chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

## Target

[image: Benzo(k)fluoranthene]

## Trial

I drew benzene rings one by one.  To get the rightmost benzene rings aligned correctly, I used `[:0]`.  I attempted to use a pair of hooks `?` so that the two positions will be connected.

```tex
\documentclass{article}‎
‎\usepackage{chemfig}‎
‎\begin{document}‎
\chemfig{*6(=-(*6(=-(-([:0]*6(=-=-(*6(=-=-?=))--)))=(-?)-=))--=-)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Problem

The middle benzene ring and the top right ring aren't well connected.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\def\myang{\fpeval{asind((1-sqrt(3))/2)}} % -21.47070143243995
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(=-(*6(=-(-[:\myang]*6([:0]=-=-(*6(=-=-?=))--))=?-=))--=-)}
\end{document}
```

[image]